# How do I export a sliced psd file as a single jpeg image optimized for web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-format, slices

I am a beginner at photoshop and am going a bit crazy here:

I have a flowchart and am trying to use the slicing tool to include URLs into my flowchart image. However, when I optimize it for the web and export as a jpeg I don't get my image but 6 slices of the image in one folder.
Is there any way to export as the same image because I am not sure what to do with with all these files in order to upload them to the web!

Comment: In the `Save for web` dialog, after you click `Save…`, you'll get another window, and at the bottom you'll find a dropdown menu: `Format: Image only`. You should change that to `Format: Html and images`. The html file is the thing that will contain the images all stitched up and links in correct places. If you do want to save a single image instead of 6 individual ones, you will have to delete the slices, save and write the html file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to just "Save As" and select JPEG as your format and whatever degree of compression you'd like to apply.

The whole point of slices is to export the design as separate images to utilize in your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The point of slicing the image is to get the small versions (aka the 6 files in your folder). You then would need to recreate the image in html/css and add your sliced images as the bg of the flowchart. You can then add a link tag ontop giving the illusion that it is a single image.

Hopefully this is clear enough. If not let me know and ill see if I can make an example :)